# LINQ Select From 3 Tables Dish/Images/ImageDish

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I have a problem doing a select from 3 tables. I'm using 3 tables because one product can have more than one image.

[Print DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fr0r.png)

Then I have my LINQ.

```
  public List<DishModel> GetDish(int dish)
    {
        var query = (from m in db.Dish
            join i in db.ImageDish on m.idDish equals i.idDish
            join t in db.TypeDish on m.idTypeDish equals t.idTypeDish
            where m.idTypeDish == dish
            select new DishModel()
            {          
                Name = m.name,
                CalorificValue = m.calorificValue,
                Price = m.price,
                ShortName = m.shortName,
                Time = m.manufactureTime,
                Description = m.description,
                UrlImageList = new List<string>()
                {
                    i.Image.urlImage
                }

            }).ToList();
        return query;
    }
```

With that LINQ I get

```
[{"Time":"asdasd","CalorificValue":"123","BeveragesList":null,"DishEnum":0,"Id":null,"UrlImageList":["sugestao.jpeg"],"Name":"asdasd","ShortName":"asdasd","Description":"asdas","Price":"12"},{"Time":"123","CalorificValue":"12","BeveragesList":null,"DishEnum":0,"Id":null,"UrlImageList":["sugestao.jpeg"],"Name":"asdasdasd","ShortName":"asdasd","Description":"sdasd","Price":"12"},{"Time":"123","CalorificValue":"12","BeveragesList":null,"DishEnum":0,"Id":null,"UrlImageList":["bebida.jpeg"],"Name":"asdasdasd","ShortName":"asdasd","Description":"sdasd","Price":"12"},{"Time":"123","CalorificValue":"123","BeveragesList":null,"DishEnum":0,"Id":null,"UrlImageList":["sugestao.jpeg"],"Name":"asdasd","ShortName":"qweqw","Description":"asdasd","Price":"12"},{"Time":"12","CalorificValue":"12","BeveragesList":null,"DishEnum":0,"Id":null,"UrlImageList":["pexels-photo-59016.jpeg"],"Name":"azores","ShortName":"asdasd","Description":"A região do Douro localiza-se no Nordeste de Portugal, rodeada pelas serras do Marão e Montemuro. A área vitícola ocupa cerca de 40000 hectares, apesar da região se prolongar por cerca de 250000 hectares. O rio Douro e os seus afluentes, como por exemplo o Tua e o Corgo, correm em vales profundos e a maior parte das plantações são encaixadas nas bacias hidrográficas dos rios.","Price":"12"},{"Time":"12","CalorificValue":"2312","BeveragesList":null,"DishEnum":0,"Id":null,"UrlImageList":["sugestao.jpeg"],"Name":"asdasd","ShortName":"asdas","Description":"asdasda","Price":"12"},{"Time":"12","CalorificValue":"2312","BeveragesList":null,"DishEnum":0,"Id":null,"UrlImageList":["bebida.jpeg"],"Name":"asdasd","ShortName":"asdas","Description":"asdasda","Price":"12"},{"Time":"12","CalorificValue":"2312","BeveragesList":null,"DishEnum":0,"Id":null,"UrlImageList":["Atum-Peixe-Desenho.jpg"],"Name":"asdasd","ShortName":"asdas","Description":"asdasda","Price":"12"}]
```

He is selecting same product more than one time because of the list of images, I don't know what to do.
What is the best way to process the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group join to join dish with all its images:

```
 var query = from m in db.Dish
             join t in db.TypeDish on m.idTypeDish equals t.idTypeDish
             join i in db.ImageDish on m.idDish equals i.idDish into g           
             where m.idTypeDish == dish
             select new DishModel()
             {          
                 Name = m.name,
                 CalorificValue = m.calorificValue,
                 Price = m.price,
                 ShortName = m.shortName,
                 Time = m.manufactureTime,
                 Description = m.description,
                 UrlImageList = g.Select(i => i.Image.urlImage).ToList()
             };
```

Comment: Thank you, you save my day!